# How to setUserState?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$app->setUserState('com_users.reset.user', $user->id);
$userId = $app->getUserState('com_users.reset.user');
```

This

```
echo $userId;
```

will print nothing

```
echo $user->id;
```

will print the user id correctly.

How can I setUserState ?

I found that in libraries/joomla/application/application.php the function getUserState is failing when if (!is_null($registry)) and returns null

```
public function setUserState($key, $value)
    {
        $session = JFactory::getSession();
        $registry = $session->get('registry');

        if (!is_null($registry))
        {
            return $registry->set($key, $value);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I'm a little confused, what are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: Have you tried using `echo $userId;` instead of `echo userId;`? Note the missing `$`

Comment: Actually I am debugging the remind me password functionality of joomla. It seems that after he returns from the e-mail he can't reset his password.And as I debuged the problem it seems that setUserState is not actually setting anything..

Comment: No, I typed it wrong here. It's with a dollar

Comment: hmm I haven't heard of any problems regarding the password resetting. Have you edited any core Joomla files? Are you running the latest version of the Joomla 2.5 series? (2.5.16)

Comment: There's a bug in 3.2.  But where are you setting $user?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I am not sure what caused this. But if for a reason the "registry" session variable is not working then you can initialize it like this. And it works.

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('registry',   new JRegistry('session'));
```